# Docker + Rspec + Capybara - arguments[0] is undefined

Tags: selenium, rspec, selenium-webdriver, docker

I'm trying to get my specs working headlessly in docker - They run fine locally on my mac but when I run them inside the docker container I get this error (repeated multiple times)

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError:
   arguments[0] is undefined
 # [remote server] https://foobar.com/ line 68 > Function:1:1:in `anonymous'
 # [remote server] https://foobar.com/:68:20:in `handleEvaluateEvent'
 # ./spec/features/foo_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>
```

Xvfb is running: `Xvfb :99.0 -screen 0 1366x768x16`

I've also tried doing a `xvfb-run rspec` and got the same errors.

spec_helper.rb:

```
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
```

What's going on that this can't run inside docker?

Comment: I'm having this issue just running feature specs on my Mac. Totally stumped...

Comment: I downgraded my version of Firefox to 34.0.5 and it seems to be working for me.

Comment: Downgrading Firefox worked for me, too. Thanks! My guess is that this is a bug in the `selenium-webdriver` gem.

Comment: Wow, downgrading to 34.0.5 worked for me too.  See this post for how to keep Firefox from updating automatically.  https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/993765

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is this:

```
>> webdriver.execute_script("return typeof arguments[0]", "foo")
=> "undefined"
```

Apparently this is a bug with Firefox 35 and webdriver. There is an issue open for it - https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8390.