# Rails Feature tests failing after Yosemite upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, osx-yosemite

Immediately after upgrading my Mac to Yosemite, some feature tests started failing, specifically steps using the `fill_in` method.  The following step definition fails on the first fill_in.

```
def sign_in
  visit '/users/sign_in'
  fill_in "Email", :with => @visitor[:email]
  fill_in "Password", :with => @visitor[:password]
  click_button "Log in"
end
```

I get the following error;

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::JavascriptError: arguments[0] is undefined
```

It was passing before the upgrade.  Anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was a Firefox update that broke things.  I downgraded from 35.0 to 34.0.5 and the tests are passing now.  See this post [Docker + Rspec + Capybara - arguments[0] is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27334933/docker-rspec-capybara-arguments0-is-undefined)

Here is a link to a selenium bug report on the issue. https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8390&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary